# how to create a List<String> class object

Tags: java, generics, mockito

```
List<String> list = mock(List<String>.class);
```

here is a invalid syntax，how to pass a `List<String>` type to mock()?

Comment: I thought all parametrized classes (like `List<whatever>`) only differ at compile time, and in run time it's just `List`, due to type erasure? So, what you need is _syntactically_ `List.class`; no idea how do you pass the parametrization information to your `mock`.

Comment: You should state in the question that you are using mockito.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer is you can't.  At runtime it's just `List.class` due to type erasure.  If your mocking framework needs to know the type parameter there must be a different way to pass it in.

Comment: You don't. Right on the Mockito front page is an example of mocking `LinkedList`.  It uses just `LinkedList.class` without any type parameter.